# How to make browser save a remote file and get informed by a callback with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have encountered a problem with my Java script/jQuery code.
I want to make a piece of code which could fulfill the following requirement:
1.Make the browser save my remote binary file, let's say http://192.168.0.100/system/diagdata
2.Since the preparing the file in the server side with cost some time(usually around 40s), so I need a callback to let me know when the data will be ready to download(the file itself is very small, so let's ignore the actually data transmit duration) so that I could display some kind of loading page to tell the user the downloading procedure is on the way.

At first, I make a piece of code like this without callback:

```
var elemIF = document.createElement("iframe");   
elemIF.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/system/diagdata';   
elemIF.style.display = "none";   
document.body.appendChild(elemIF);
```

It works well(but without callback)
Then in order to make callback possible, then I added some code like this:

```
var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
var elemIF = document.createElement("iframe");   
elemIF.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/system/diagdata';   
elemIF.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(elemIF);   
elemIF.defer = 'defer';
if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    sc.onreadystatechange = function() {
                              if ((that.readyState == 'loaded'
                             ||that.readyState == 'complete') ) {
                              }
                          }
}
else { // Chrome, Safari, Firefox
    elemIF.onload = function() {
                        alert("onload");
                      };
    elemIF.onerror = function(e) {
                         alert("onerror");
                      };
}
deferred.promise();
```

After I run this piece of code, the "onload" has been called, but the browser did not tend to save the file "diagdata" but try to load it and report a parsing error exception.

Did anyone have a substitute solution which could not only make browser save the binary file but also will callback to inform the data ready status?

Comment: Let me clarify something, "make browser save a remote file" means save the remote file to my local disk.

Comment: So you want to download the file `diagdata` to the client machine?

Comment: Hi Barmar: Yes, that exactly what I want.

Comment: I don't think Javascript can save the file by itself. The server has to send a `Content-disposition: attachment` header so that the file will be saved instead of being displayed in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The first piece of code will make browser save that file. But that piece of code won't tell me when those data is ready to download. What I need is a callback to give me a change to know when those data is ready so that I have a chance to clear the loading page.